# Bot Custom OAuth provider

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I would like to register oauth for my Bot, but the provider is not in the list. Hence would like to create a new one. How this can be done, can someone give me the idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this documentation - [Other identity providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-identity-providers?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=adv1%2Cga2#other-identity-providers).

It says  - Azure supports generic OAuth2, which allows you to use your own identity provider.

You can choose from two generic identity provider implementations

- Generic OAuth 2
- OAuth 2 generic provider

Comment: Yup I am trying this one. But when I close the window without authenticating, the Search Message extension gets freeze.

Comment: Could you check if you are getting some console error? Is it same behavior across Web and Desktop?

Comment: I receive this error on browser:  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')
    at t.parseQueryString (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.2-app.min-5b6648e.js:1:778468)

Comment: When you are successfully authenticating? Is the messaging extension working fine?

Comment: Please refer the section on how to [set up authentication](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-openbadges/wiki/Deployment-guide#step-4-set-up-authentication-for-bot) and [file](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-openbadges/blob/e9f6e2b1911bbc377130cd98b04e966b4e270664/Source/Microsoft.Teams.App.Badges/Helpers/TokenHelper.cs) showing the authentication flow.